# Bókun signature generation; what am I missing?

Tags: php, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to connect to the Bókun Rest API. The [documentation](https://bokun.helpkit.so/booking-api-restful/vU6sCfxwYdJWd1QAcLt12i/configuring-the-platform-for-api-usage-and-authentication/sFiGRpo4detkmrZPcWtQPj) says:

> Let's say our secret key is 23e2c7da7f7048e5b46f96bc91324800. Now, let's calculate the signature. First select values of the following fields:
>
> Date = 2013-11-09 14:33:46
> Access key = de235a6a15c340b6b1e1cb5f3687d04a
> HTTP method = POST
> Path = /activity.json/search?lang=EN&currency=ISK
>
> So when concatenating the string (date+accesskey+httpmethod+path) becomes:
>
> 2013-11-09 14:33:46de235a6a15c340b6b1e1cb5f3687d04aPOST/activity.json/search?lang=EN&> currency=ISK
>
> We then use this, along with the secret key to calculate the HmacSHA1 value for the signature, and Base64 encode it:
>
> X-Bokun-Signature : XrOiTYa9Y34zscnLCsAEh8ieoyo=

So I'm trying to implement this with PHP but hit a rock wall, because the signature does not match the output of the [test tool](https://hash.online-convert.com/sha1-generator). This is my implementation:

```
$access_key = 'my_access_key';
$secret_key = 'my_secret_key';
$method = 'POST';
$path = '/activity.json/search?currency=EUR&lang=FI';
$date = '2022-08-31 12:00:00';

$signature_base = $date . $access_key . $method . $path;
$signature = hash_hmac('sha1', $signature_base, $secret_key, true);
$signature_sha1 = sha1($signature_base); // This is for test purposes
$signature_base64 = base64_encode($signature);

echo $signature_base; // 2022-08-31 12:00:00my_access_keyPOST/activity.json/search?currency=EUR&lang=FI
echo $signature_sha1; // 3e81b830958602b54419c61070582519460c36c6
echo $signature_base64; // 5q22t52R0qHk43ssRHs6kyLBSiw=
```

Then, these are the values I entered into the test tool:
[image: Test tool values]

This is the test tool output:

> hex: 3e81b830958602b54419c61070582519460c36c6

> HEX: 3E81B830958602B54419C61070582519460C36C6

> h:e:x: 3e:81:b8:30:95:86:02:b5:44:19:c6:10:70:58:25:19:46:0c:36:c6

> base64: PoG4MJWGArVEGcYQcFglGUYMNsY=

What is interesting is that the hex output matches my test SHA1 hash but the base64 does not and I do not understand why. It leads me to suspect the output of `hash_hmac` but what am I doing wrong? I tried to use both false and true as the last (4th) argument. With `false` the base64 encoded output does not resemble the example in the documentation. It has too many characters in comparison. With `true` the resemblance is the same but the value is not.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking; with the sample values from the explanation, your code produces _exactly_ the base64-encoded hash it says it should, https://3v4l.org/e07bO

Comment: I can see that. It means my implementation is probably correct. It's just that the documentation says "use this tool to check your signature hash" but when I do, it produces results that imply that my implementation is not correct. That in tandem with the API returning a "Invalid key" error makes me suspect my sanity.